# My python calculator returns an exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been getting the exception "can only concatenate str (not "float") to str" whenever I try to run it. I've already tried a try except block but it just gives me a different exception.

```
num1 = float(input("Please enter the first number: "))
operator = input("Please choose the operator (+) for addition, (-) for subtraction, (*) for multiplication, (/) for division: ")
num2 = float(input("Please enter the second number: "))
result = float()
while result == float():
        if operator == '+':
            result = float(num1 + num2)
            print("The result is " + float(result))
            print("All done.")
        elif operator == '-':
            result = float(num1 - num2)
            print("The result is " + float(result))
            print("All done.")
        elif operator == '*':
            result = float(num1 * num2)
            print("The result is " + float(result))
            print("All done.")
        elif operator == '/':
            if num2 == 0:
                print("You can't divide anything by 0.")
            else:
                result = float(num1 / num2)
                print("The result is " + float(result))
                print("All done.")
```

Comment: result is already a float, do you mean to make it a string to print like `print("The result is " + str(result))`

Comment: There's no need to use `float()` in `float(num1 + num2)`. Since the variables are floats, the sum will also be a float.

Comment: Your code contains several unwanted typecasting, maybe try to eliminate them and you'll find your answer. First one is at line 4, there's no need to initialize `result = float()` since Python does everything dynamically so result variable will automatically gets created once it interprets line 7, second one is at line 7, since both of your values are float their sum will be float as well. Lastly learn how to use f-strings they will surely going to help you and make your task much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to concatenate a float value with a string value.

In order to fix this value you should do the following:

```
if operator == '+':
        result = float(num1 + num2)
        print("The result is " + str(result))
        print("All done.")
    elif operator == '-':
        result = float(num1 - num2)
        print("The result is " + str(result))
        print("All done.")
    elif operator == '*':
        result = float(num1 * num2)
        print("The result is " + str(result))
        print("All done.")
    elif operator == '/':
        if num2 == 0:
            print("You can't divide anything by 0.")
        else:
            result = float(num1 / num2)
            print("The result is " + str(result))
            print("All done.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to replace all :

```
print("The result is "+ float(result))
```

by:

```
print("The result is ", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a float to the string. You have multiple ways to fix this.

**Method 1**

Convert float to string. You can use `str()` function for this.

```
print("The result is " + str(result))
```

**Method 2**

You can use `,` instead of `+`

```
print("The result is", result)
```

**Method 3**

You can use string formatting

```
print(f"The result is {result}")
```

or

```
print("The result is {}".format(result))
```